# Phoenix: how to avoid including Bootstrap/HTML5 boilerplate in generated CSS production file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

When I deployed my Phoenix app in production for the first time I saw that my CSS were broken due to the `app.css`generated file include not wanted CSS such as Bootstrap and HTML5 boilerplate.
I imagine they are included by brunch when compiling in production mode.
How to avoid it?

PS: when using SSH to send local files to a remote server see my comment to Dmitry answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just delete everything in `web/static/css/app.css` file. And then recompile your project

Comment: @Thank you Dmitry. This is a silly question because I've already done this, but now I figured out the problem: the commands I use to copy files from my local machine to my remote server diff files so they don't replace existing app.css with my files, rather they add mines, so in the end I get both and that's why...I need to delete web files in the server first...

Comment: Update. This boilerplate css is now in the file /assets/css/phoenix.css which can be deleted.